# Not able to redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I have created a user login and logout system. After login the user gets redirected to his dashboard. Currently with the help of correct url, the user can go directly to dashboard without login. to restrict this i used the following code so that user can not access any internal pages before login

```
class User extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('no_access', 'sorry you are not allowed');
                        redirect('user/noaccess');
                    }
            }
    }
```

Now when i try to access the dashboard with a correct url, but without login i am not able to view it but is is also not etting redirected to noaccess. i am getting the following error

> the page not redirecting properly

Can anyone please tell how to do this properly

Comment: Is your base url set? and Have you followed the filename and class naming style for codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes it is set, and i have followed everything

Comment: @Sam, try with `redirect(base_url(user/noaccess));`

Comment: @MayankVadiya, Codeigniter's `redirect` function will automatically add the base_url to the segment argument.

Comment: @Sam, Is the `url` helper loaded? There is a `public function noaccess()` defined in the `User` controller - right?

Answer (score 0):

Sam consider doing this

```
public function logged_in()
{
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if (!isset($logged_in) || $logged_in != true)
    {
      redirect("Checkin"); //insert your login page
    }
}
```

Then in your controller for page access you can call this method

```
public function admin()
  {
  $this->logged_in();
  //rest of controller here
  }
```

This will prevent anyone from accessing your admin pages without login. The "logged_in" method will redirect them to the login page. That way you are not redirecting to yet another page(user/noaccess) or using flashdata. Use the $this->logged_in(); on any method that requires login